# Toast from implemented callback

Tags: android, callback, android-asynctask, progressdialog, toast

I have an activity that roughly follows this structure:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements myCallback{
   //Code

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       new myAsyncTask(myActivity.this).execute();
   }
   public void myCallback(Context context){
   //Code
   Toast.makeText(context,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

And myAsyncTask has the myCallback() interface defined and it calls it eventually. No matter what I do, whatever UI element I try to show, be it a Toast or a ProgressDialog, it won't show. Nor do I get any exceptions. The rest of the callback code gets perfectly executed. Why is this?

Comment: In which method of your asynctask are you calling myCallback()? doInBackground or onPostExecute()? And why are you passing the Activity to the constructor of the AsyncTask?

Comment: Please add your AsyncTask Code

Comment: Please consider starting Class and Interface names with an upper case character.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements myCallback{
   //Code
   Context mContext;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mContext = this;
       new myAsyncTask(getApplicationContext()).execute();
   }
   public void myCallback(Context context){
   //Code
   Toast.makeText(mContext,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the only difference the use of the mContext field? Didn't work.

Comment: Nothing regarding this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you move Toast.makeText() into the onCreate method, does it work?

Comment: It's working now. I just restarted the phone. Must have been some weird issue.

Comment: Just one final question, when my AsyncTask calls the callback, is it being executed from within the main activity or within the AsyncTask?

Comment: It'll be executed from the Activity. However, i think the problem was that you were creating a new instance of the Activity in the AsyncTask to call the method, which meant that your Context could be null or incorrect.

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see what "context" is being set as. and isnt the onPostExecute() method used for displaying changes to the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using context , use getApplicationContext... i hope it will show toast... like this

```
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```